# Rails 3: Social Stream Gem. Where is the code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, social-networking, social-stream

I've installed social_stream according to the README ( https://github.com/ging/social_stream ) and it works fine, however, I'd like to have the code in my app/ directory and the code isn't there.

The same question arises for Devise and other gems. When I install it, I'd like to have access to the controllers, models, views, etc but it seems nothing is in the app/.

What do I have to do in order to put the code there and being able to change it as I'd like? Or, access it in other folder.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the url that explain how to change the views
https://github.com/ging/social_stream/wiki/How-to-change-controllers%2C-models-and-views

Comment: social_stream is an engine. That means you just have to take a copy of the code (github or gem unpack) into a temp folder and simply copy the file to its corresponding location in your application and make changes.

Answer (score 1):

"gem which social_stream" tells me the place where the gem is installed so I can change the code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know these plugins specifically, but Rails plugins in general get put in `vendor/plugins`.

Comment: I'm surprised. But if it isn't there, I'm afraid I don't know. Have you tried searching for it?

Comment: It's not a plugin.  It's a gem.

Comment: I found the place where it has been installed. However, I have other question but I'll use other topic because it's a bit different. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, they are within vendor folders.

Unless you have a good explanation, you should not put the addon within same app folder.

Imagine if social_stream gets upgraded and new features are released, you would be lost.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't quite understand how I can change the views. Social_stream is a social network (à la facebook) but I imagine I could be able to change the views to fit what I want.

Comment: hummmm....I don't know custom guidelines for social_stream. Maybe you could branch it in git and start doing your custom...try to contact who's developing it

Answer (score -1):

With Bundler you can freeze all your gems in your directory. You can try that.

Having the file in your app directory is not really a good advice.